# Python 3.8.7 acts in a funny way in Windows 10

Tags: python, pip

This is my first question :)

So, ya, the title is kinda my question. I recently installed Python 3.8.7 after installing Python 3.9.0 then uninstalling it because of some build issues with a GUI library ([arcade](https://arcade.academy)).

Python 3.8.7 has a folder with the same name in 2 locations (`C:\Program Files\Python38\`, `C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\`). I wonder whether that is supposed to be there?

If yes, then I am unable to access `pyinstaller` CLI using `python -m pyinstaller --version`  (get the `C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe: No module named pyinstaller` error). I can see that following the path in explorer, the **`Scripts` folder has no scripts, even though I installed many (`pyinstaller` being one of them).**

On the other hand, when navigating to the 2nd path mentioned above, I see that **the `Scripts` folder DOES have the `pyinstaller.exe` file and it does work as intended.**

Do I have a broken installation? Or is it just Python's problem and I need to find a trick?

**NOTE: Before upgrading to Python 3.9, I was using Python 3.8.7 with ease. No problems with anything, including `pyinstaller`**.

## Summary

- Python having 2 folders in different locations
- Running `python -m package_name` tries to run package_name from `C:\Program Files\Python38\Scripts`, whereas `python -m pip install package_name` installs to `C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts`
- Also, can anyone explain me how I can add a `PATH` variable for `pip` in Windows 10?

P.S. please do excuse me if the question is not clear. This is my first question, so I tried to make as much as sense as possible.

## EDIT

When using a `venv`, all is fine and works as intended

Comment: what is your question exactly? why is python in two folders?

Comment: @Arandomcoder  that's kinda my question, but another part of it is why `pip` installs in a different directory, but `python -m package_name` runs it in a different directory

Comment: the second folder is probably some utilities from python 3.9. Thats why it doens't affect any of your python 3.8 stuff.

Comment: ooh. but then shouldn't the 3.9 uninstaller remove the contents of that folder? and shouldn't it be named to something like `Python39`?

Comment: oh, and, if so, shouldn't `pip` install to the 1st path mentioned? I mean to say, shouldn't Python 3.8's pip install to Python 3.8's Scripts directory?

Comment: First directory is the installation of Python itself, the second one is where third-party packages are installed for your user only (so they are not accessible if you log in as another user). Otherwise, you'd need administrator permissions each time you'd want to `pip install` something.

Comment: Answering the second question, `C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts` should be added to `PATH`.

Comment: @hoefling, thanks for the help. that clarified my question. for future users, can you please make this as an answer for the question?